# Error occurred while enabling plugin v1.0 (Is it up to date?)

Tags: java, minecraft

I bought a custom plugin for my server. But atm it doesn't work because some reasons. The developer got his holidays and I want to try to fix it on my own.

So the console give me following error:

```
[17:17:08 WARN]: [ZolrahFactionsCore] Default system encoding may have misread config.yml from plugin jar
[17:17:08 ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling ZolrahFactionsCore v1.0 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.bukkit.ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes(ChatColor.java:324) ~[server.jar:git-Hyperion-7f1b6c1]
        at com.zolrah.factionscore.lang.Chat.color(Chat.java:11) ~[?:?]
        at com.zolrah.factionscore.lang.Lang.<init>(Lang.java:18) ~[?:?]
        at com.zolrah.factionscore.Core.onEnable(Core.java:51) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:321) ~[server.jar:git-Hyperion-7f1b6c1]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:332) [server.jar:git-Hyperion-7f1b6c1]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:404) [server.jar:git-Hyperion-7f1b6c1]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:359) [server.jar:git-Hyperion-7f1b6c1]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:318) [server.jar:git-Hyperion-7f1b6c1]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.s(MinecraftServer.java:403) [server.jar:git-Hyperion-7f1b6c1]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.k(MinecraftServer.java:367) [server.jar:git-Hyperion-7f1b6c1]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:322) [server.jar:git-Hyperion-7f1b6c1]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:283) [server.jar:git-Hyperion-7f1b6c1]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:558) [server.jar:git-Hyperion-7f1b6c1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
```

I went over the config file and there isn't a syntax error. I also checked it via web yml-checker.
Can someone help me out where the error could be?

Comment: My guess is that it tries to replace the alternate color characters (starting with & instead of §) in a null string. However it is impossible to debug without providing the source code of the plugin and the configuration file. If you have not permission to do that, you should consult with the plugin's owner instead.

Comment: tibetiroka is totally right. Did you fix your issue now ? Should I explain more ?